How to mint token where an authority belongs to program in pure rust
I would like to make a program which might issue tokens. The idea is to create a token (mint), then create ATA for the payer user and pass all this thing to my program.
Program:
fn process_instruction<'a>(
  program_id: &'a Pubkey,
  accounts: &'a [AccountInfo<'a>],
  _instruction_data: &'a [u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

let payer = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let mint = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let ata = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let token_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

invoke(
    &mint_to(
        &spl_token::id(),
        mint.key,
        ata.key,
        &program_id,
        &[],
        1,
    )?,
    &[
        mint.clone(),
        ata.clone(),
        payer.clone(),
    ],
)?;

Client side:
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
const blockhashInfo = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
let tx = new Transaction(blockhashInfo);
let tokenId = Keypair.generate();
const rentExemptMintLamports = await spl.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
let ata = spl.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(tokenId.publicKey, payer.publicKey);
tx.add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: tokenId.publicKey,
        space: spl.MINT_SIZE,
        lamports: rentExemptMintLamports,
        programId: spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    spl.createInitializeMint2Instruction(
        tokenId.publicKey,
        0,
        programId,
        null,
        spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    ),
    spl.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        payer.publicKey,
        ata,
        payer.publicKey,
        tokenId.publicKey
    ),
    new TransactionInstruction({
        programId: programId,
        keys: [
            {pubkey: payer.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: true},
            {pubkey: tokenId.publicKey, isWritable: false, isSigner: true},
            {pubkey: ata, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
        ],
        data: Buffer.from([]),
    })
);

tx.sign(payer);

let hash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [payer, tokenId]);

When I'm trying it I get an error: "An account required by the instruction is missing". I'm still not sure should it work or not. I didn't find any examples where the program is authorized minter. Maybe I do not understand some basic things and trying to do what's impossible?
Rust dependencies:
[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.18"
spl-token = { version="3.5.0", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }

Client level:
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.8",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.94.0",


I've figured out that there is no way to sign a CPI (cross-program instruction) invocation by the caller program (at least I didn't find it). But there is another way to do the similar things: is using PDA (program derived address).
PDA makes by hashing program address with some seed and bump. Bump is required to be sure that you PDA is not on elliptic curve. It's just a bite which is chosen by brute force from 255 up to 0. Seed is any byte sequence, e.g. a string. There are methods to generate PDA: on client side it is PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync, on server side is Pubkey::find_program_address. Both of them returns array with a public key and a bump byte.
There is some internal logic for PDA which marks this address as an signer if do the invocation from the program and provide proper seed + bump. Method invoke_signed has to be used for that purposes. You can find an example below.
So, in summary, it works by following: you generate PDA on the client side, put the PDA address as an owner of token and then, in the program, sign a CPI with the same PDA.
Program:
fn process_instruction<'a>(
    _program_id: &'a Pubkey,
    accounts: &'a [AccountInfo<'a>],
    _instruction_data: &'a [u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let _payer = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let token = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let destination_ata = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let authorized_pda = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let spl_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    invoke_signed(
        &mint_to(
            &spl_token::id(),
            token.key,
            destination_ata.key,
            authorized_pda.key,
            &[],
            1,
        )?,
        &[
            token.clone(),
            destination_ata.clone(),
            authorized_pda.clone(),
        ],
        &[
            &[
                b"mint_authority_seed",
                &[u8::MAX]
            ]
        ]
    )?;

    Ok(())
}

I've hardcoded bump as u8::MAX, but if you want more flexibility you should send it as a parameter or generate by calling Pubkey::find_program_address in the smart contract.
Client side:
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const blockhashInfo = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    let tx = new Transaction(blockhashInfo);
    let tokenId = Keypair.generate();

    console.info("Token Id: " + tokenId.publicKey);

    const rentExemptMintLamports = await spl.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

    let authorizePda = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("mint_authority_seed")], programId);
    console.info("PDA: " + authorizePda[0] + ", bump: " + authorizePda[1]);

    tx.add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: tokenId.publicKey,
            space: spl.MINT_SIZE,
            lamports: rentExemptMintLamports,
            programId: spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        spl.createInitializeMintInstruction(
            tokenId.publicKey,
            0,
            authorizePda[0],
            null,
            spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        ),
    )
    let destinationAta = spl.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(tokenId.publicKey, payer.publicKey);

    tx.add(
        spl.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
            payer.publicKey,
            destinationAta,
            payer.publicKey,
            tokenId.publicKey
        )
    );

    tx.add(
        new TransactionInstruction({
            programId: programId,
            keys: [
                {pubkey: payer.publicKey, isWritable: false, isSigner: true},
                {pubkey: tokenId.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
                {pubkey: destinationAta, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
                {pubkey: authorizePda[0], isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
                {pubkey: spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isWritable: false, isSigner: false},
            ],
            data: Buffer.from([]),
        })
    );

    tx.sign(payer);

    let hash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [payer, tokenId]);
    console.log("tx hash: " + hash);

